# calculate a sequence of expressions efficiently

Tags: r, performance

I have some data

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:30, n, replace = T),
  y = sample(1:30, n, replace = T),
  z = sample(1:30, n, replace = T)
)
```

and vector with expressions, they may be different.

```
rules <- c("df$x[i] < df$y[i-2] - df$x[i]", 
           "df$y[i] >= mean(df$x)",
           "df$y[i] == 20",
           "df$z[i-30] >= df$x[5]",
           "df$y[i-5] == 16",
           "df$x[10] > sd(as.matrix(df[(i-5):i,]))")
```

Next, I have a function that sequentially searches for the triggering of the first expression, then the second, and so on

```
seq_rules <- function(df, rules, show=T){
  
ln <- length(rules)
res <- matrix(0,nrow = ln, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row","res")))
n <- 1

  for(i in 30:nrow(df)){
    if(eval(str2expression(rules[n]))){
      res[n,"row"] <- i
      res[n,"res"] <- 1
      if(show) print( cbind.data.frame(df[i,], rule=rules[n], row=i))
      n <- n+1
    }
    if(n>ln) break
  }
res
}
```

I would like to speed up my code.
How would you write this code to make it as fast as possible?
I also like your solution to be identical to mine on different `seeds`

=======================================

if the rules are represented as already evaluated functions

```
Frules <- lapply(rules,\(x) eval(str2expression(paste("function(i) {", x ,"}"))))
```

Then i can gain a little speed due to the absence of `eval(str2expression..))` in the loop

New function

```
Fseq_rules <- function(df, rules){
  ln <- length(rules)
  res <- matrix(0,nrow = ln, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row","res")))
  n <- 1
for(i in 30:nrow(df)){
    if(rules[[n]](i)){
        res[n,"row"] <- i
        res[n,"res"] <- 1
        n <- n+1
      }
    if(n>ln) break
  }
  res
}
```

---

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Fseq_rules(df, Frules),
                                seq_rules(df, rules,show = F),times = 100)
Unit: milliseconds
                           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
          Fseq_rules(df, Frules) 1.083315 1.118951 1.283135 1.156011 1.247808 5.601309   100
 seq_rules(df, rules, show = F) 2.495045 2.545790 2.779712 2.607938 2.861662 6.243315   100
```

Comment: Why would one ever want to specify a ruleset like this?

Comment: To find a sequence of events (rules) in very noisy data

Comment: I am not questioning the rules, but the way how you define them.

Comment: This is just an example.
I wanted to show that the rules are not trivial, they can be complex, nested, take into account indexing, etc.

Comment: I want to have maximum freedom in designing my rules and I don’t see a way to create tidy data for this if that’s what you’re implying

Comment: And is it correct that each rule can trigger once, at most? I.e., the first rule is applied to each row until it triggers. Then, the next rule is applied to the next rows until it triggers etc?

Comment: Yes, you understood everything correctly.
if I need a rule to work several times, I'll just create several identical rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much faster than your original:

```r
rules2 <- c(
  "x[i] < y[i-2] - x[i]", 
  "y[i] >= mean(x)",
  "y[i] == 20",
  "z[i-30] >= x[5]",
  "y[i-5] == 16",
  "x[10] > sd(as.matrix(df[(i-5):i,]))"
)

seq_rules2 <- function(df, rules) {
  rules <- sapply(rules, str2expression)
  M <- length(rules)
  res <- matrix(0L, nrow = M, ncol = 2L, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "res")))
  j <- 1L
  
  for (i in 30:nrow(df)) {
    if (eval(rules[[j]], envir = df)) {
      res[j, ] <- c(i, 1L)
      j <- j + 1L
    }
    if(j > M) break
  }
  res
}

bench::mark(seq_rules(df, rules), seq_rules2(df, rules2))
```

[image]

You will gain a lot of speed if you replace `df` by a matrix. And change the rules accordingly:

```
M <- as.matrix(df)

rules_matrix <- c(
  "df[i, 'x'] < y[i-2] - x[i]", 
  "df[i, 'y'] >= mean(df[, 'x'])",
  "df[i, 'y'] == 20",
  "df[i-30, 'z'] >= df[5, 'x']",
  "df[i-5, 'y'] == 16",
  "df[10, 'x'] > sd(df[(i-5):i, ])"
)

seq_rules_matrix <- function(df, rules) {
  rules <- sapply(rules, str2expression)
  M <- length(rules)
  res <- matrix(0L, nrow = M, ncol = 2L, dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "res")))
  j <- 1L
  
  for (i in 30:nrow(df)) {
    if (eval(rules[[j]])) {
      res[j, ] <- c(i, 1L)
      j <- j + 1L
    }
    if(j > M) break
  }
  res
}

bench::mark(
  mat = seq_rules_matrix(M, rules_matrix),
  df = seq_rules2(df, rules2)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is strange, but on a matrix instead of a dataframe, I got the result 3 times worse with my function `Fseq_rules `

Comment: Hmm. See my update on that point.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was useful for me...
It’s a pity, but this is probably the maximum that can be speeded up in my case.

Comment: If you cannot vectorize all conditions, it is difficult to make things faster... All conditions in your example can easily be vectorized, btw., except the rolling matrix standard deviation.

Comment: Can you please show an example of your solution, but without the rules that bother you?

Comment: For a moment I forgot the sequential application of the rules... so I am probably wrong. My original thought was doing something like: `with(df, x < dplyr::lag(y, 2) - x)` etc.

Comment: sequential application of the rules..  -> Yes, this breaks the whole vectorization style, or I don’t know something

Comment: You could apply all rules to all rows to get a logical matrix. And then evaluate the desired output from this matrix. It can be faster or slower, depending on large data/rule sets are